# the position of cursor when first click a textarea

Tags: html

I found a problem that I am puzzled.
It's just a simple , Under normal circumstances,when I click a textarea, the cursor is always at the beginning of the textarea,but today when i type the code like this

```
  <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
```

on **a Chrome extesion web page**,the cursor changes it's position with the click position. I swear there's no extra JS or css on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same strange problem. I hacked around it by using the following:

```
document.getElementById('element-id').innerText = '';
```

I would love to know the real reason for it occurring.

Answer (score 3):

Check in your code if you have tabs in between opening and closing textarea tags. Some IDEs insert tabs upon auto-formatting.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be a any space or in tab between `<textarea></textarea>` open and close tags.

If got space or tab between tags it will behave strangely.